# How to filter MongoDB (aggregate), based on ROOT _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB and mongoose in my node js app. I have two collections:

```
reasonCollection: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d8d662f89f8b1d0970797d"),
    "name" : "Reason name",
    "types": [
        ObjectId("58d8d7a67c8f3c1e2e172789"),  // id of typesCollection object
        ObjectId("58d8d7a67c8f3c1e2e17278e")
    ]
}
typesCollection: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d8d7a67c8f3c1e2e172785"),
    "name" : "Type name",
    "reason" : ObjectId("58d8d662f89f8b1d0970797d"), // id of reasonCollection object
    "deductedLeave" : false,
    "description" : "",
}
```

I want to get an object like this, containing all 'reasons' and as its children, all 'types' that have a matching 'reason' field as its parent.

```
{
    "reasonName": "Reason name",
    "reasonId": "reasonCollection ObjectId",
    "types": {
        "name": "typesCollection object name"
        "id": "typesCollection ObjectId"
    }
}
```

I thought this is the situation where I would use MongoDB's aggregate, and filter results.

```
db.reasonCollection.aggregate([
{
    '$lookup': {
        'from': 'types',
        'localField': 'name',
        'foreignField': 'types',
        'as': 'newData'
    }
},
{
    '$project': {
        '_id': 1,
        'name': 1,
        'types': 1,
        '__v': 1,
        'newData': {
                '$filter': {
                    'input': '$newData',
                    'as': 'element',
                    'cond': {
                        '$eq': [ '$$element._id', 'ROOT._id' ] // Here, I need to match reasonId with reasonCollection ObjectId
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
])
```

Comment: which mongo version are you using?

Comment: @sidgate 3.2.12

Comment: Have you tried `'$eq': [ '$$element._id', '$_id' ]`?

Comment: @sidgate Yes, and again 0 matches.

Comment: Did you mean to compare `'$eq': [ '$$element.reason', '$_id' ]` ?